# is there a way to handle a click event whithout assigning id?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have a webpage full of buttons , for opening a modal with a description related to the button..
the webpage is for mobile repair service requests...

```
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="left">
                    <img src="#" />
                </div>
                <div class="middle">
                    <h3 class="Breakge">
                        Breakge
                    </h3>
                    <div class="hyperclicks">
                        <div class="click">Udskiftning af Skærm
                            <div class="sector hidden">
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>Original Kvalitet </p><p class="priceitem">2299.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>TopKvalitet </p><p class="priceitem">1199.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>KobiKvalitet  </p><p class="priceitem">799.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="click">Udskiftning af Batteri
                            <div class="sector hidden">
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>Batteri </p><p class="priceitem">549,99,-</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>TopKvakitet Batteri </p><p class="priceitem">649.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="click">Udskiftning af Bagglas
                            <div class="sector hidden">
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>Bagglas </p><p class="priceitem">999.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>Bagglas og Ramme </p><p class="priceitem">1699.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="click">Udskiftning af Højtaler
                            <div class="sector hidden">
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>Ørehøjtaler </p><p class="priceitem">599.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>Højtaler (Musik) </p><p class="priceitem">749.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="click">Udskiftning af Kamera
                            <div class="sector hidden">
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>FrontKamera </p><p class="priceitem">899.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>Bagkamera </p><p class="priceitem">1299.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>Lins </p><p class="priceitem">349.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="click">Udskiftning af Ladestik
                            <div class="sector hidden">
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>Ladestik </p><p class="priceitem">749.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>Vibrator </p><p class="priceitem">749.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="click">Udskiftning af knapper
                            <div class="sector hidden">
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>Tænd/Sluk funktion </p><p class="priceitem">749.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>Volume/Lydløs knapper </p><p class="priceitem">749.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="click">Udskiftning af Vibrator
                            <div class="sector hidden">
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>Vibrator </p><p class="priceitem">749.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="click">Ander
                            <div class="sector hidden">
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>Fejlfinding </p><p class="priceitem">349.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>Softwer / Gendannekse </p><p class="priceitem">349.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p> Microchip </p><p class="priceitem">fra 799,99,-</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="click">Tilbehør
                            <div class="sector hidden">
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>PanserGlas </p><p class="priceitem">249.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="priceflex">
                                    <p>Cover </p><p class="priceitem">249.99,-</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="right" id="right">
                    <h3 class="Prices">
                        Prices
                    </h3>
                    <div class="hyperprices">
                        <div class="description">
                            Place Description Title Here
                        </div>
                        <div class="seperateline">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btngroup">
                        <div class="rightbtn">
                            <input type="button" id="btnClose" class="btn" value="Close">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

there is ten sectors , and for each of them it will show another div with description and details

```
<div class="sector" id="sector1">
                <div class="priceflex">
                    
                    <p>Original Kvalitet </p><p class="priceitem">2299.99,-</p>
                    </div>              
                <div class="priceflex">
            <p>TopKvalitet </p><p class="priceitem">1199.99,-</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="priceflex">
            <p>KobiKvalitet  </p><p class="priceitem">799.99,-</p>
                    </div>
                    
            </div>
```

i'm using this code to show and hide each div(sector)

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var btnClose = document.getElementById("btnClose");

var divState = {};
function showhidesector(id,id2) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var divid = document.getElementById(id);
        divState[id] = (divState[id]) ? false : true;
        for (var div in divState){
            if (divState[div] && div != id){ 
                document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none'; // hide
                divState[div] = false; 
            }
        }
        divid.style.display = (divid.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block');
    }
}
```

so my question is , is there anyway to achieve this without assigning id's for each element ?
because i have to create a modal for every mobile device (about 120 devices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nest `div.sector` within `div.click`. Use [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). If  `div.click` is clicked add a class that hides all non hidden `div.sector` within `div.hyperclicks`. Then remove that `hidden` class from `div.sector` from the clicked element.

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.matches(`.click`)) {
    evt.target.closest(`.hyperclicks`).querySelectorAll(`div .sector:not(.hidden)`)
      .forEach(d => d.classList.add(`hidden`));
    evt.target.querySelector(`.sector`).classList.remove(`hidden`);
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.sector {
  margin-left: 2rem;
  color: green;
}

.click {
  margin: 0.8rem 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="hyperclicks">
  <div class="click">Udskiftning af Skærm
    <div class="sector hidden">
      <div class="priceflex">
        <div>Original Kvalitet </div>
        <div class="priceitem">2299.99,-</div>
      </div>
      <div class="priceflex">
        <div>TopKvalitet </div>
        <div class="priceitem">1199.99,-</div>
      </div>
      <div class="priceflex">
        <div>KobiKvalitet </div>
        <div class="priceitem">799.99,-</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="click">Udskiftning af Batteri
    <div class="sector hidden">
      <div class="priceflex">
        <div>Original Kvalitet </div>
        <div class="priceitem">2199.99,-</div>
      </div>
      <div class="priceflex">
        <div>TopKvalitet </div>
        <div class="priceitem">1299.99,-</div>
      </div>
      <div class="priceflex">
        <div>KobiKvalitet </div>
        <div class="priceitem">699.99,-</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Kooilnc your code looks like the solution to my problem , but it's not adding the event to the click div , do you have any idea why ? i'm using this on a wordpress website

Comment: Not sure what you mean. *events* are never added, *event listeners* (and handlers for it) are. Here [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) is used, which means you only need one listener for the `click` event (see `document.addEventListener` in the snippet). The handler (function `handle`) only executes if a click event originated from any of the `div.click`.

Comment: i updated my question so you can see the whole html document

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by using `querySelectorAll()` to retrieve all the `p.click` elements, then looping through them to add the same event handler to each one.

The related sector can targeted by using a `data` attribute to store the selector for each element. Try this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p.click').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let sectorId = e.target.dataset.sectorid;
    document.querySelector(sectorId).classList.toggle('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.sector { display: none; }
.sector.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<div class="hyperclicks">
  <p class="click" id="click1" data-sectorid="#sector1">Udskiftning af Skærm</p>
  <p class="click" id="click2" data-sectorid="#sector2">Udskiftning af Batteri</p>
  <!-- other p elements here... -->
</div>

<div class="sector" id="sector1">
  <div class="priceflex">
    <p>Original Kvalitet (SECTOR 1)</p>
    <p class="priceitem">2299.99,-</p>
  </div>
  <div class="priceflex">
    <p>TopKvalitet </p>
    <p class="priceitem">1199.99,-</p>
  </div>
  <div class="priceflex">
    <p>KobiKvalitet </p>
    <p class="priceitem">799.99,-</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sector" id="sector2">
  <div class="priceflex">
    <p>Original Kvalitet (SECTOR 2)</p>
    <p class="priceitem">199.99,-</p>
  </div>
  <div class="priceflex">
    <p>TopKvalitet </p>
    <p class="priceitem">299.99,-</p>
  </div>
  <div class="priceflex">
    <p>KobiKvalitet </p>
    <p class="priceitem">399.99,-</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response Rory !! , is there a way to dispense the sector id ?

Comment: Not really - you need a method of relating the `p` to the `div`. You could use DOM traversal, but it would be very brittle and easily broken.

Comment: problem not solved , because  i still need to create 10 sectors for each modal .... that would be like a thousand id